Error trying to add dropdown ranking filter on top of other conditional filters in plotly dashboard
I currently have a working dashboard that allows dropdown filters to filter data displayed on dashboard. However, I face issues trying to introduce a new concept that allow the dashboard to go 2 ways.

Manually filter the dropdown filters to display data(Originally working)
New dropdown filter that filters data that displays data only fulfilling this criteria then autofill names of other manual dropdown filters.(issues- cause the crash)

So I am able to obtain the dataframe that fulfils best performing excess return but I cannot display it for both ways now, mainly because I introduced a new variable(auto_select_er) that is suppose to determine whether the first or second menthod should be used, none or the former.
The code that is affected is
Utils.py
def get_data(universes, firms, products, selected_type,auto_select_best_er=False,consol_db=consol_db_orig):
    if len(bm_universe.loc[bm_universe['Asset Class'] == universes]) != 0:
        GENERIC_BM = bm_universe.loc[(bm_universe['Asset Class'] == universes) & (bm_universe['Type'] == 'Generic')]['Benchmark'].iloc[0]
    else:
        GENERIC_BM = None
#    print(consol_db)
    if auto_select_best_er:
        df = consol_db.copy()
        df["bm_label"] = ""

        if df['Product Name_index'].str.contains("Pref").any():
        #  print('hi im here')
            df['Gross TR'] = df['Gross TR_mandates']
            df['Gross BM TR'] = df['Pref BM Gross TR']
            df["bm_label"] = "(Preferred)"
        else:
        # print('hi im  not here')
            df['Gross TR'] = df['Gross TR_mandates']#df['Gross TR_index']
            df['Gross BM TR'] = df['Gross TR_index']#df['Default BM Gross TR']
       # df[f'Gross ER'] = (1 + df[f'Gross TR']) / (1 + df['Gross BM TR']) - 1#df[f'Gross TR'] - df['Gross BM TR']# Arithmetic
       # df['Gross BM ER'] = df['Gross BM TR']# df[f'Gross TR'] - df['Gross BM TR']
       # group_cols = ['Firm Name_mandates', 'Product Name_mandates', 'Universe', 'Product Name_index']
      #  df['Cumulative ER'] = df.groupby(group_cols)['Gross ER'].apply(lambda x: (1 + x).cumprod() - 1)
        #df['Actual Cumulative ER'] = (1 + df['Gross ER']).cumprod() - 1
        best_product_row = df.loc[df['Cumulative ER'].idxmax()]
        
        # Extract best product information
        universes = best_product_row['Universe']
        firms = best_product_row['Firm Name_mandates']
        products = best_product_row['Product Name_mandates']
        selected_type = best_product_row['Product Name_index']
        df = df.loc[
            (df['Universe'] == universes) &
            (df['Firm Name_mandates'] == firms) &
            (df['Product Name_mandates'] == products) &
            (df['Product Name_index'] == selected_type) 
        ]
        print('filter',df)
    else:


        df = consol_db.loc[
            # (consol_db['Asset Level 1'] == asset_class) &
            # (consol_db['Manager'] == manager)  
            (consol_db['Universe'] == universes) &
            (consol_db['Firm Name_mandates'] == firms) &
            (consol_db['Product Name_mandates'] == products) &
            (consol_db['Product Name_index'] == selected_type) 
        ]
        print('filtermercer',df)
        df["bm_label"] = ""

        if df['Product Name_index'].str.contains("Pref").any():
        #  print('hi im here')
            df['Gross TR'] = df['Gross TR_mandates']
            df['Gross BM TR'] = df['Pref BM Gross TR']
            df["bm_label"] = "(Preferred)"
            #df['Product Name_index'] = df['Product Name_index'] + " (Pref)"
        # print(df['Product Name_index'])
        else:
        # print('hi im  not here')
            df['Gross TR'] = df['Gross TR_mandates']#df['Gross TR_index']
            df['Gross BM TR'] = df['Gross TR_index']#df['Default BM Gross TR']

Callback.py
@app.callback(
    Output('dashboard', 'children'),
    [
        Input('dropdown-universe', 'value'),
        Input('dropdown-firm', 'value'),
        Input('dropdown-product', 'value'),
        Input('select-type-dropdown', 'value'),
        Input('select-filter', 'value')
       # Input('dropdown-data-type', 'value')
    ]
)
def update_dashboard(universes, firms, products,selected_type, auto_select_best_er= False):
    if universes and firms and products and selected_type or auto_select_best_er:
        # try:
        global df
        global GENERIC_BM
        global mandate_stats
        global bm_label
        # Get data from main consol db
        #df,  mandate_stats = get_data(asset_class, manager)
        df,bm_label,GENERIC_BM,  mandate_stats = get_data(universes, firms, products,selected_type, auto_select_best_er)
        

        FIRST_DATE, LAST_DATE = get_first_last_dates(df)

I would like to see the default to be None as the original filter. Should the best ER be selected, the other filters should be updated with the correct names belonging to each filter. If possible, im wondering if i can add specifics to the filter, meaning after i chose to display best performing excess return, user can select specific  universe like "GEQ" on top of the current filter to display the best performing  results belonging to this universe instead of all data from just the best performing filter itself.
Layout.py
layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            html.Label('Universe', className='dropdown-label'),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='dropdown-universe',
                options=[
                    {'label': asset, 'value': asset} for asset in asset_classes
                ],
                value='GEQ',#'GEMEQ',#'GEMEQ',
                placeholder="Select Universe",
                className='dropdown'
            )
        ], className='dropdown-container'),

        html.Div([
            html.Label('Firm', className='dropdown-label'),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='dropdown-firm',
                # options=[
                #     {'label': 'JP Morgan', 'value': 'JP Morgan'},
                # ],
                value='Manulife Investment Management',#'abrdn (Aberdeen)',#'AGF Investments',#'Alquity Investment Management',#'J.P. Morgan Investment Management Inc.',
                placeholder="Select Firm",
                className='dropdown'
            )
        ], className='dropdown-container'),

        html.Div([
            html.Label('Product', className='dropdown-label'),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='dropdown-product',
                value='Manulife Investment Management Global Quality Value',#'abrdn (Aberdeen) Emerging Markets Equity',#'AGF Investments AGF Emerging Markets Equity',#'Alquity Investment Management Alquity Future World Equity Fund',#'J.P. Morgan Investment Management Inc. JPM GEM Research Enhanced Equities',
                placeholder="Select Product",
                className='dropdown'
            )
        ], className='dropdown-container'),
                # Adding the Benchmark dropdown
        html.Div([
            html.Label('Benchmark', className='dropdown-label'),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='select-type-dropdown',
                # options=[
                #     {'label': 'Preferred', 'value': 'Preferred'},
                #     {'label': 'Default', 'value': 'Default'}
                # ],
               # value='Default',  # Set 'Default' as the default choice
                 value = 'MSCI World Value-ND',#'MSCI EM-GD (Pref)',
                placeholder="Select Benchmark",
                className='dropdown'
            )
        ], className='dropdown-container'),

        html.Div([
            html.Label('Filters', className='dropdown-label'),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='select-filter',
                options=[
                    {'label': 'None', 'value': 'None'},
                    {'label': 'Best Performing Strategy on Excess Return', 'value': 'best_er'}
                ],
                 value = 'None',#'MSCI EM-GD (Pref)',
                placeholder="Select Filter",
                className='dropdown'
            )
        ], className='dropdown-container'),
    ],
    className='dashboard-header'),

    html.Div(id='dashboard')
])

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1373, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\_callback.py", line 465, in add_context
    output_value = _invoke_callback(func, *func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\_callback.py", line 40, in _invoke_callback
    return func(*args, **kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
  File "c:\Users\mas_yhchieng\Desktop\plotly\KAY_mandates\frontend\components\callbacks.py", line 354, in update_dashboard
    df,bm_label,GENERIC_BM,  mandate_stats = get_data(universes, firms, products,selected_type, auto_select_best_er)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

